# Javascript: Accessing public method of prototype does not work

Tags: javascript, public, prototype-programming

I want to create a simple class in Javascript with only one public function as follows:

```
function A(myTitle) { 
    var title = "";
    this.getTitle = function() {
        return title;
    };
    title = myTitle;
};

var anInstance = new A("first");
console.log("anInstance.getTitle(): '"+anInstance.getTitle()+"'"); 
// expecting to return "first"
```

This does work as expected.

Now I want to add this class as a prototype to a new class, that includes a new title variable, so that the getTitle() method returns the value of the variable instead:

```
var myA = new Object();
myA.title ="second";
myA.prototype = anInstance;
console.log("myA.getTitle(): '"+myA.getTitle()+"'"); 
// expecting to return "second"
```

But instead of the expected "second", it results in the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myA.getTitle()')
```

What is the problem with this function access?

**Update:**
The key point for my question is the following: In my application I will create several thousand instances of type "A" and several more of other comparable types. Thus memory efficiency and performance do matter. So I thought it would be great to create the according methods (several more will follow, `getTitle` is only one example) only once and the "data objects" reference these methods. Is this possible?

Comment: Here you have a nice example about classes and Inheritance http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is instance variables (and that's all I see you using), what's wrong with idiomatic JavaScript:

```
function A(title) { 
    this.title = title;
};

A.prototype.getTitle = function() {
    return this.title;
};

var anInstance = new A("first");
var myA = new A("second");
```

You can implement both Self-like prototypal OO and Smalltalk-like class-based OO on top of JavaScript, but this only makes sense in case of inheritance hierarchies, where the flat model of JS (which favors composition over inheritance - it's easy to add new methods to the prototype or `apply()` arbitrary constructor functions, but you'll have to jump through some hoops to make inheritance work properly) is not sufficient.

As to why your code can't work: your `getTitle()` method returns a lexical instead of an instance variable, which takes no part in property resolution via the prototype chain and thus can't be overwritten your way; also, `.prototype` is a property of constructor functions which is used to initialize the internal *[[Prototype]]* property of newly created instances - setting `.prototype` on general objects has no effect whatsoever on property resolution.

Comment: Please see my update above regarding the background of my question.

Comment: all schemes (idiomatic, prototypal, class-based) can be used in a way so function objects will be shared; for your example code, just move `getTitle()` out of the constructor and use `this.title` instead of a lexical...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly JavaScript is not a class based language.

This works just as well and am unsure what you are trying to achieve with your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRtD2/

Comment: You changed my code slightly, but in a significant way: The instance `myA` in your code is a new instance of `A`. In that way, the methods of `A` are copied for each instance of it. I thought to do it in the way above, so that the functions do exist only once in memory. Is this possible?